# Issues in creating VLAN interface using netplan on ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, netplan, ifconfig, vlan

I have been trying to create a vlan interface on my ubuntu VM which has one network adapter.
I could see that the vlan link has been successfully created, but I don't see any traffic passing through. Could it be due the similar mac address on both the links. Here is my netplan config along with ifconfig and ip link output.

[netplan yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7v13.png)
network:
ethernets:
ens160:
addresses:
- 172.16.1.227/24
gateway4: 172.16.1.1
nameservers:
addresses:
- 8.8.8.8

vlans:
v.206:
id: 206
link: ens160
addresses:
- 172.16.206.211/24
gateway4: 172.16.206.1
macaddress: 00:00:00:00:02:06

[ifconfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSWk9.png)

ens160: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
inet 172.16.1.227  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 172.16.1.255
inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fe1d:a540  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
ether 00:0c:29:1d:a5:40  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
RX packets 15251  bytes 1755640 (1.7 MB)
RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
TX packets 3954  bytes 2834818 (2.8 MB)
TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10
loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
RX packets 118  bytes 9478 (9.4 KB)
RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
TX packets 118  bytes 9478 (9.4 KB)
TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

v.206: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
inet 172.16.206.211  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 172.16.206.255
inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fe1d:a540  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
ether 00:0c:29:1d:a5:40  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
TX packets 60  bytes 4112 (4.1 KB)
TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

[Ip link output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaLRS.png)

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: ens160: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether 00:0c:29:1d:a5:40 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: v.206@ens160: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether 00:0c:29:1d:a5:40 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

Comment: Use code formatting to format the command output

Comment: Sorry, not familiar with code formating, Can u take a look at the images uploaded ?

Comment: [Why *do* people post code as images?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/374700/4424636)